# CSS Gradient - too many color breaks

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am running into an issue with css linear-gradients. I am looking to make clean color breaks at certain percentages. But it seems to start blurring the colors when I add more than a certain number:

This is the example of the css gradient with "too many" color breaks - and blurs where it should not:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 25%, #042750 25% 28%, #ffffff 28% 29%, #03aeef 29% 31%, #ffffff 31% 32%, #042750 32% 90%, #ffffff 90% 91%, #03aeef 91% 93%, #ffffff 93% 94%, #ffd900 94% 96%, #ffffff 96% 97%, #042750 97% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This is an example of it with it enough color breaks so it doesn't blur:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 25%, #042750 25% 28%, #ffffff 28% 29%, #03aeef 29% 31%, #ffffff 31% 32%, #042750 32% 90%, #ffffff 90% 91%, #03aeef 91% 100%)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Both examples don't blur here...

Comment: I see significant blurring in the first example. MacOS 10.15.4. Chrome 81.0.4044.138. Looks fine in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: The odd thing is, it goes away entirely once I use less than 8 color changes.

Comment: Also using a Chromium based browser and seeing blurring - No issues on Safari

Comment: My testing in Firefox seems to show no blurring

Comment: I encountered the same problem.https://jsfiddle.net/Richardinho/nxcp3h6z/56/ I have reported it to Chrome. It only seems to be on Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In such case it's better to use multiple gradient:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: 
    /* Color                       position /width height   */
    linear-gradient(#03aeef,#03aeef)  50% 0 / 5%  100%, /* top layer */
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)        50% 0 / 10% 100%,
    linear-gradient(#03aeef,#03aeef)  87% 0 / 5%  100%,
    linear-gradient(#ffd900 ,#ffd900) 94% 0 / 5%  100%,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)        95% 0 / 15% 100%,
    linear-gradient(#042750,#042750)  right / 60% 100%; /* bottom layer */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @Artsen it's not weird but it's a lot easier for browser to handle different *images* with unique color and put them above each other than creating one image with multiple colors and caclulate the color stop. Here you have no color transition since in each gradient I have only one color and you cannot have blur between 2 gradients

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for the answer. I didn't know it could be done like this.